# How to make sure that the loaded file can be detected by a js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this code in the file `assets/URL.js`:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").on("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var TheURL = $(this).attr('href');
        if(TheURL){
            $("#MyDiv").load(TheURL , { name: '' }, 
                function() {
                    alert("done");
                });
        }
    });
});
```

And what it does is that if an `<a>` element is clicked, the function above prevents the page from going to that page then it gets the url and load it into the `div` with the id `MyDiv`.

Now this is the code of `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/URL.js?v=1"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="MyDiv">
      <a href="files/1.html"></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the code of `files/1.html` is:

```
<a href="2.html">2</a>
```

now, when I click on `<a>` in the file `index.html` the content of the `<div>` with the id `MyDiv` changes the the content of `file/1.html` without the page reloading.

But when I click `<a>` in the file `file/1.html` the page reloads and goes to `file/2.html` and doesn't follow the code in `assets/URL.js`, how can I force it to follow it and just replace the content of the `<div>` with the id `MyDiv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the eventhandlers again when the dynamic html is loaded, right now you only bind the click event to the existing A tags in index.html, not the future ones in dynamic loaded content like 1.html

You could try something like:

```
$(function(){
  RefreshEventHandlers();
});

function RefreshEventHandlers() {
    $("a").on("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var TheURL = $(this).attr('href');
        if(TheURL){
            $("#MyDiv").load(TheURL , { name: '' }, 
                function() {
                    alert("done");
                    RefreshEventHandlers(); // bind click to newly added A tags.
            });
        }
    });
}
```

To make sure the click event handlers are set on all new A tags